# Highcharts: Addling link on Grouped Categories

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am using Highcharts with the Black Label Group Categories [plugin](http://blacklabel.github.io/grouped_categories/). I would like to add a link to the category representing the year. This is where I'm at: http://jsfiddle.net/trn_/zru45jy4/

The idea is to let the user click "2011" and then update the chart with monthly details from that year.

Normally one could use:

```
$('.highcharts-axis-labels text, .highcharts-axis-labels span').click(function () {
    console.log(this.textContent || this.innerText);
});
```

But that doesn't seem work with the plugin. Any ideas? I would love a click event solution, but I'm really open for any solution or ideas.. :)

Comment: Well, your solution works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/zru45jy4/5/ :)

Comment: Weird. Now it works here too. Maybe I just needed a browser restart, or Easter vacation.. ;) Thanks for pointing out the obvious! What would be the best way to deal with this question now? Delete it?

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea :) I would just post as answer that your solution works. I guess that was caused by some caching issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as it turns out my question is the solution. And it didn't work because of non-related things. Maybe as Paweł Fus says it was caused by some caching issue on my side.